# How to reference TextViews inside embed LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout layout resource file (xml) that has multiple LinearLayouts of different orientations embedded inside. Inside one of these embedded LinearLayouts I have some TextViews that I want to change dynamically from my java code, but for some reason, when ever I try and set an ID these TextViews, it throws an error. Do you know what's causing this? Also, is there any fix or alternate way to access these TextViews within the embedded LinearLayout? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Nevermind, I feel like an idiot. I forgot the "@+id/" 
I am sorry if I wasted time for some people. I guess I have been coding a bit too much the last four days. I have been up till 2:00 every day

Comment: "... it throws an error. Do you know what's causing this?" - the message of the error will almost certainly tell you that. Unfortunately you haven't included the error, so no, we don't know what's causing this. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: post some code here, which parts displays the error.
are you sure you are using correct syntax android:id="@+id/text1"

Comment: "Do you know what's causing this?" We are programmers not magicians, though it looks like that to normal people. Post some code and logcat then we will talk.

Comment: Okay, I posted the code. I was just hesitant to post code, because last time, I got down voted for putting up too much code.

Comment: Nevermind, I feel like an idiot. I forgot the "@+id/" 
I am sorry if I wasted time for some people. I guess I have been coding a bit too much the last four days. I have been up till 2:00 every day

Comment: Does anyone know how I can delete the question? It was a really stupid question resulting from me not looking through my code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to assign an id to each `TextView` inside the xml layout file. If you haven't explicitly declared the appropriate id resources (the usual case), then you need to use a special syntax:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/view_id . . . />
```

The `@+` syntax will automatically create an id of the indicated name if none exists. (See the [docs for `android:id`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html#idvalue).)

If you use the syntax:

```
<TextView android:id="@id/view_id . . . />
```

then you need to explicitly have an id resource created (in res/values/any_file.xml):

```
<item type="id" name="view_id" />
```

See the [docs on ID resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id).

Whichever method you use, you can get to the `TextView` in code using:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view_id);
```

P.S. After seeing your code, the problem is very clear: as the error message says, you cannot use a string as a view id. So, for instance, you need to replace `android:id="limVal"` with `android:id="@+id/limVal"` and similarly throughout your layout file. Then in your code you can use

```
TextView limValView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.limVal);
```